# devcontainers with MongoDB on special port

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

i am trying to run my project (Nextjs - MongoDB) on vscode using [Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) extension

but i cannot find how to run mongo on a new port other then 27017 which is the predefined default port for connection.

Reading the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference) it seems that i should use **forwardPorts**

my devcontainer.json

```
    {
    "name": "Node.js & Mongo DB",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",

    // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
    "settings": {},

    // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
    "extensions": [
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
        "mongodb.mongodb-vscode" 
    ],

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    "forwardPorts": [2000, 27017],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "yarn install",

    // Comment out connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    "remoteUser": "node"
}
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
    version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        # [Choice] Node.js version: 16, 14, 12
        VARIANT: 14
        # On Linux, you may need to update USER_UID and USER_GID below if not your local UID is not 1000.
        USER_UID: 1000
        USER_GID: 1000

    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace:cached

    # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
    command: sleep infinity

    # Runs app on the same network as the database container, allows "forwardPorts" in devcontainer.json function.
    network_mode: service:db

    # Uncomment the next line to use a non-root user for all processes.
    # user: node

    # Use "forwardPorts" in **devcontainer.json** to forward an app port locally.
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db

    # Uncomment to change startup options
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: local

    # Add "forwardPorts": ["27017"] to **devcontainer.json** to forward MongoDB locally.
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)

volumes:
  mongodb-data:
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

add `ports` under `db` section

```
db:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27020
    # Uncomment to change startup options
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: local

    # Add "forwardPorts": ["27017"] to **devcontainer.json** to forward MongoDB locally.
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)

volumes:
  mongodb-data:
```

Comment: it didn't work, if you noticed they said "# (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)"